# How do I export the content of a page as either jpg or pdf with Highcharts and scrollable data?

Tags: javascript, pdf, export, highcharts, jpeg

I have a page that contains some data and some Highcharts. Highcharts has some fantastic functionality for exporting the chart as an image. How do I include the contents of a table or div to be exported with the chart so that there is one big image or pdf that contains the chart and the data?
What I have tried so far, none of which is ideal, is:

html2canvas, seems like the best solution but does not seem to include Highcarts. Maybe I'm doing something wrong as the documentation doesn't seem great and I have been unable to find any good examples from Goggling that include the charts.

The second best solution that I have come across is including the data in the Highcharts. Example of this is located:
    http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/z9zXM/
This could work, but would destroy the current formatting on the page. In other words, it would be an ugly solution :).

The other solutions that I found are to do with screenshots, but this would not capture the full page.

The ideal solution that may or may not exist is, using JavaScript in someway to combine a div or table with the Highchart into a pdf or jpg, is this possible and if it is, where would I find an example?

Comment: take a look at http://pdfcrowd.com/html-to-pdf-api/

Comment: hello i am also used highcharts in angularjs and i am also go for the export data in pdf file but i am click on download pdf format than getting data in pdf format file but that time also redirect to other link "https://export.highcharts.com/" this link is so how can stop this redirection do you know about it?

Answer (score 0):

how about combining native Highcharts export functionality with html2canvas?

First, you export Highcharts to a file. I'm guessing that it's enough to know the URL you have to call to get an image.

Second, you use your standard html2canvas magic to produce a document without a chart. (You may need to specify width and height of the div with chart so it doesn't collapse in exported file).

Finally, you use gd or imagemagick to paste one onto another and serve back to client.

Answer (score 0):

It's to simple you can use this code for capture the screenshot of particular area 
you have to define the div id in html2canvas. I'm using here 2 div-:
div id="car"
div id ="chartContainer"
if you want to capture only cars then use **car** i'm capture here car only you can change **chartContainer** for capture the graph
**html2canvas($('#car')**
copy and paste this code

```html
<html>
    <head>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.5/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
    
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
        animationEnabled: true,
        theme: "light2",
        title:{
            text: "Simple Line Chart"
        },
        axisY:{
            includeZero: false
        },
        data: [{        
            type: "line",       
            dataPoints: [
                { y: 450 },
                { y: 414},
                { y: 520, indexLabel: "highest",markerColor: "red", markerType: "triangle" },
                { y: 460 },
                { y: 450 },
                { y: 500 },
                { y: 480 },
                { y: 480 },
                { y: 410 , indexLabel: "lowest",markerColor: "DarkSlateGrey", markerType: "cross" },
                { y: 500 },
                { y: 480 },
                { y: 510 }

            ]
        }]
    });
    chart.render();
    
    }
</script>
</head>

<body bgcolor="black">
<div id="wholebody">  
<a href="javascript:genScreenshotgraph()"><button style="background:aqua; cursor:pointer">Get Screenshot of Cars onl </button> </a>

<div id="car" align="center">
    <i class="fa fa-car" style="font-size:70px;color:red;"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-car" style="font-size:60px;color:red;"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-car" style="font-size:50px;color:red;"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-car" style="font-size:20px;color:red;"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-car" style="font-size:50px;color:red;"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-car" style="font-size:60px;color:red;"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-car" style="font-size:70px;color:red;"></i>
</div>
<br>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 370px; width: 100%;"></div>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>

<div id="box1">
</div>
</div>>
</body>

<script>

function genScreenshotgraph() 
{
    html2canvas($('#car'), {
        
      onrendered: function(canvas) {

        var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
        var pdf = new jsPDF();
        pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, 0, -180, -180);
        pdf.save("download.pdf");
        
      
      
      }
     });

}

</script>

</html>
```